# NavigationBar Hides and Shows Depending on User Scroll direction IOS SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

This idea has been driving em crazy as I haven't been able to find a suitable solution despite the multiple threads its created. so basically I want to be able to hide the `navigationbar` upon swipe, but I also want to be able to call it back upon an up swipe (like facebook ) and I want to do it without having to use any code from GitHub.

here's my idea of how to do such:

Get the direction in which a user is swiping on a screen (or in my case a `UIScrollView` with a `UITableView` inside) and if the direction is down, the `navigationbar` disappears and if the direction is up, the `navigationbar` slides back down. The only issue is that I don't see any clear way for doing this from a `UIScrollView`. can someone help me with a step by step of how such can be implemented?

Comment: `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true`

Comment: Try self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true. If you want to hide on tap self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true. To hide when keyboard appears self.navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears = true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set navigation controller property **hidesBarsOnSwipe** to **true**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
}
```

You can also you also use third party library https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/HidingNavigationBar

You can read how to hide in apple developer documentation 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller